# Hosting WCF Service with NetTcpRelayBinding in IIS: host closes when called

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I'm having trouble hosting my WCF service with NetTcpRelayBinding in IIS.  When I activate the service by browsing the WSDL it publishes a relay to Azure service bus, but as soon as I try and call it the service host closes and the relay disappears.  The only exceptions I can see service side are SocketException: remote server closed connection.  If I host the same service in a Console host it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have Non-Http Activation enabled in Windows Features.

Answer (score 0):

Strange.  I had all activation on except MSMQ.  I've added this and it now works as I would expect.  I've also remove MSMQ activation and it still works.  Bizarre.